# Dereferencing a head pointer from a double pointer to access node item?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes, dereference

In the linked list below, I'm adding a node to the beginning of a linked list by passing in the address of head.

Then make a new node with data, and since a pointer to a pointer was passed in, made the new node contain the dereferenced head's address, before making the same dereferenced head point to the new node at the beginning of the list.

My question is why can't I use the dereferenced `head` to set data?

For example using `*head->item = 4` is not possible at the start of the `add_to_beginning` function even though `*head` contains the first nodes memory address?

I'm using a pointer to `head` (containing head's address), then dereferencing it which is the address of the first node so I should have access to its data?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int item;
    struct node *link;
};

void add_to_beginning(struct node **head, int data) {
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->item = data;
    temp->link = NULL;
    temp->link = *head;
    *head = temp;
}

void print(struct node *head);

int main()
{
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->item = 45;
    head->link = NULL;

    add_to_beginning(&head, 40);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
void print(struct node *head) {
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("Linked list is empty.\n");

    struct node *ptr = head;

    int count = 0;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("Node %d: %d\n", count, ptr->item);
        ptr = ptr->link;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: *why can't I use the dereferenced head to set data*. Why do you think you can't? If there is a specific error or incorrect behaviour then please provide that info in the question. Though, why would you want to as that would *replace* the head rather than add a new node?

Comment: So adding the line *head->item = 4; is not possible in the beginning of the add_to_beginning function. My compiler says "error: '*head' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?" There is no good reason to do this I'm just wondering why it's not allowing me to.

Comment: When asking a question please provide all relevant info. Any error message is obviously important. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65536624/edit) the question to add the exact and complete error.

Comment: Try: `(*head)->item = 4`.  The `->` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator so explicit bracketing is needed.

Comment: Of right! That fixed it, Thank you!

Comment: `temp->link = NULL;` is not required in `add_to_beginning` , since you are storing `temp->link = *head;` immediately

Comment: yep thank you, I'm in the habit of immediately setting every node link to NULL from traumatic experience